# page not found (404) notes.url

Tags: python, django

when i run the server this show up

Page not found (404)

Using the URLconf defined in notes.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/ notes/ The empty path didn't match any of these

notes urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include , path

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
path('notes/', include('notes_app.urls'))
]
```

notes_app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

 urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$' , views.all_notes , name='all_notes'),
  url(r'^(?P<id>[\d]+)$', views.detail , name='note_detail')

  ]
```

view

```
  from django.shortcuts import render
  from django.http import HttpResponse
  from .models import Note
  # Create your views here.

  ## show all notes
  def all_notes(request):
   # return HttpResponse('<h1> Welcome in Django Abdulrahman </h1>' , {})
   all_notes = Note.objects.all()
   context = {
        'all_notes' : all_notes
    }

    return HttpResponse (request , 'all_notes.html' , context)

   ## show one note
   def detail(request , id):
   note - Note.objects.get(id=id)
   context = {
  'note' : Note
   }
[enter image description here][1]   return render(request,'note_detail.html' , context)
```

Comment: Well the error is correct: there is nothing that will match the empty path. Why do you expect it to match anything?

Comment: how can i fix it

Comment: I think before fixing something, it pays off to first realize why this problem occurs. Why do you expect this to render a page for an empty path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when using HttpResponse you don't pass a template :)

you pass a string, but here you passed a html file:

```py
return HttpResponse(request , 'all_notes.html' , context)
```

which doesn't work, read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse)

so just use [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) like this

```py
return render(request , 'all_notes.html' , context)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks alot it woeks for http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes   - but for the main http://127.0.0.1:800 still show up  this page  -> Using the URLconf defined in notes.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
notes/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

Comment: @d7mmmi because in the main `urls.py` you are defining every pattern in notes `urls.py` for the pattern `notes/`, i.e if you add `r^add/$` in notes' `urls.py` then you can access it via `127.0.0.1:8000/notes/add` because every pattern is assigned to `notes/` in main `urls.py`